# Unable to load apps to iPhone from Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image]

Currently having problems loading to my iPhone for testing from Xamarin Studio. When testing in the simulator there are no errors, although seen in the picture above, if I switch to testing on the physical device, I get errors relating to Mtouch.
Furthermore, after plugging the phone into the computer, the phone does not appear in the dropdown. All that appears at the bottom is 'Device'.

Cant find anything online that relates directly to the issue. Running the latest stable version of Xamarin and Xcode.

Any body know of the fix, or experiencing the sam problem?

Answer (score 0):

This generally indicates a bug in the AOT compiler. Please file a bug http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug with a project that can be used to reproduce the error.

Sometimes it's possible to work around this by disabling incremental builds in the project's iOS Build option